# JQuery attach same event to 2 objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several objects to whom I would like to attach the same event handler. So far, I'm doing this:

```
$(object).bind(event, function(event) {
    // Code
});
$(object2).bind(event, function(event) {
    // Same code
});
$(object3).bind(event, function(event) {
    // Same code again
});
```

I know there's nothing wrong with this approach (or is there), but I'm wondering if there's a shorthand method for binding the same handler for the same event to several different objects.

EDIT: what I mean is, instead of writing `object1.bind(stuff); object2.bind(stuff); object3.bind(stuff); etc` I want something like `allObjects.bind(stuff)`.

Comment: Object is a HTML element, selected by an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about,

```
$('selector1, selector2, selector3').bind(event, function(event) {
    // Same code again
});
```

**Note:** Assuming the `object1` is selector string.

Comment: Why the downvote.. please leave a reason.. why you think it is wrong.. ok Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work. Because the search for `selector1` will be inside `selector2`, etc. like `$("div", "#nav")` -> All divs in #nav

Comment: +1, but depends on what "object" is. DOM selectors could be concatenated with commata (to one selector string), for real objects you'd need to use an array: `jQuery([obj1, obj2, obj3])`

Comment: @NULL Thanks.. I think I missed the quotes.. Check now.. http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to select them all at once:

```
$(object1).add(object2).add(object3).bind(event,handler);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myFunc = function(event){
  // do something
};

$(object).bind(event, myFunc);
$(object2).bind(event, myFunc);
$(object3).bind(event, myFunc);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define an variable containing the function an then bass the object to each bind.
Like this:

```
var fn = function(event) {};
$(object).bind(fn);
$(object2).bind(fn);
$(object3).bind(fn);
```

Apendix: you can store your objecs in an array an iterate over them:

```
$([object, object2, object3]).each(function(){
    this.bind(fn);
});
```

However I don't think this is a good coding style....

Comment: What I mean is, I don't want to write `object1.bind(stuff), object2.bind(stuff)`, I want something like `allObjects.bind(stuff)`.

Comment: @Stefan: The second one does not what you expect. Don't use `$.fn.each` like this.

Comment: Hi, can you explaint to my why? I mad a sample and it works fine (even if I wouldn't use it like this). Sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CD6Np/